# How do we send a proper response using catchError in Interceptor class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, authentication, rxjs

If I get a 401 error in my project, I want to make another API call and return the response. But I came to know that catchError() will only take throwError(some error) as a return statement, I want to send a response instead of throwing an error.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
let token: string = this.CookieService.get('token');
if ((token != null) && (token !== "")) {
    let AuthRequest = this.addToken(request);
    return next.handle(AuthRequest).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        console.log(error);
        if (error.status === 401 && error.message == 'token expired') {
          // return throwError(error);
          return  this.handle401Error(request, next);
        }
        else {
          return throwError(error);
        }

      }))
  }
  else return next.handle(request).pipe(
    //  finalize(()=>this.loaderService.hide())
  );;

}


addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>)
  {
    //adding headers and returning them
    var request2: HttpRequest<any>;
    let token = this.CookieService.get('authToken');
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', token).append('Content-Type', 
   'application/json');
    request2 = request.clone({ headers: headers });
    return request2;
  }

  handle401Error(request, next)
   {
       //make another API to get a new token 
       // updating the token
       return next.handle(AuthRequest); //re-hit the API with new token
   }
  }
```

I have checked the network tab, API is getting called and I am getting the expected response, but the problem is to bring that response in the component file. Right now I am getting facing this error in the response.

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:43)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1707)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:26247)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1693)
```

Is there any way to send the expected response than throwing an error using catchError?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [retryWhen](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen) operator for retries, it catchs the error and you decide what to do inside.

For example:

```
return next.handle(req).pipe(
    // Will continue the pipe if a request attempt has succeeded without errors, or exceeded max retries.
    retryWhen((errors: Observable<any>) => errors.pipe(
        // Enable only 2 retries, +1 for the original request.
        take(this.maxRetries + 1),
        mergeMap((err: HttpErrorResponse, i: number) => {
            if (i >= this.maxRetries) {
                return throwError(err);
            }

            // retry
            return of(err);
        }),
    ))
)
```

Comment: I can able to request again when I am getting 401 responses, but the problem is How do I bring that response to the component.ts file.

Comment: the component should be oblivious that this second request actually occur. So sorry I don't follow. Maybe posting the component would help me understand